# Spring reactor webclient sequential requests with flatmap and takewhile

Tags: java, spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux, flatmap

I want to retrieve all pages from a third-party resource. To do that I wrote this:

```
final WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
     .baseUrl("http://resource.com")
     .build();
Flux.fromStream(IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1).boxed())
     .flatMap(i -> webClient.get()
          .uri("/data?page={page}", i)
          .retrieve()
          .bodyToMono(Page.class))
     .takeWhile(Page::isMoreAvailable)
     .flatMapIterable(Page::getData)
```

but it doesn't work properly. `flatMap` is called multiple times and it performs multiple requests with different pages before `takeWhile` retrieves the first response.

If I change it to this:

```
.map(i -> webClient.get()
        .uri("/data?page={page}", i)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Page.class)
        .block())
```

it works well.

So, how can I achieve this with a `flatMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so flatmap processing concurrent

```
.flatMap(i -> webClient.get()
   .uri("/data?page={page}", i)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(Page.class), 1)
```

did the trick.

Comment: Can you tell please why the second parameter to `bodyToMono` did the trick?

Comment: @StavAlfi the second parameter is to `flatMap`